# cakephp Model Relationships

Tags: cakephp, model, relationships

I have an acl controlled cake application and specifically there are two tables I am having an issue with: 'users' and 'forms'. All of my tables have a 'created_by' field which links back to users giving me the user id of the records author. This is set on save within the forms model from Auth.

The issue I have is that each form record must be authorised by a user with a role of manager prior to being visible on site. I have therefore included a 'signoff_id' field which needs to relate back to the user table id.

In my Form model I have included the following

```
public $hasOne = array(
    'User'=>array(
        'className'=>'User',
        'foreignKey'=>'created_by'
    ),
    'Signoff'=>array(
        'className'=>'User',
        'foreignKey'=>'signoff_id'
    ),
    'Db',
    'Identity'
);
```

This works ok with created_by and I get the correct info back from finds, but signoff_id is looking for a Signoff.signoff_id field (and trying to bring back all of the User table fields but substituting Signoff for User.

Any ideas gratefully received - I've tried the RT(F)M option but am no further forwards.

Comment: **hasOne** is for 1:1 relations. **belongsTo** is for M:1 relations. The Signoff relationship should be a belongsTo and _most likely_ the User relationship also.

Answer (score 0):

Finally joined the dots together ...

my Form model links back to the User model with a foreign key of 'id', and the User model links to Form with a foreign key of 'signoff_id'

Simple now I've sorted it.